# Type Checking Changed Function Signature in an Object

Tags: typescript, typechecking

## Issue

I'm creating a wrapper for [redux-starter-kit](https://redux-starter-kit.js.org/) to make it feel more like Vuex. The Github repo is [here](https://github.com/MichaelJGW/reduex/tree/master) I'm working on this [branch](https://github.com/MichaelJGW/reduex/tree/type-refactor). This project is an experiment. The issue is I can not get these reducers type-checked correctly.

## Question

If you have an object of functions like so.

```
const reducers = {
  addCounter(state:IState, payload:IActionPayload<number>):void {
    state.counter += payload.payload;
  }
}
```

And it goes through another function and takes the first parameter away. How do you keep the payload Type-checked?

I can do this with generics on a single function and typecast the return

[image]

I'm not sure how to do this dynamically for every function in an object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After hacking away all day. I learned a lot about TypeScript Types and wow is it powerful and ugly. I'm still new to this so if someone has a better option or if I'm misunderstanding something please correct me.

## Steps

1. Remove the first parameter in a function and move the second to the first position with retaining the type.
2. Loop over an object and apply step 1 to each item.
3. We will need to extract the type we are passing into `IActionPayload<number>`

## Step 1 - Function Changes

```
// Formats a Reducer Function to remove state and place the 
// payload parameter as the first parameter
type ReducerToAction <R> = R extends (...args: infer A) => any ? (payload:A[1]) => any : never
```

It works but it sure is ugly.
It is all about [conditionals](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#conditional-types). If it is a function capture the args as A with the type of `unknown[]` but because it is an array we can say `A[1]` and get our payload. So if it is a function return type `(payload:A[1]) => any` else `never`

## Step 2 - Loops

You can loop over objects with this.

```
type loop<obj> = { [key in keyof obj]: obj[key] }
```

Now we need to do Step1 to `obj[key]`

```
type loop<obj> = { [key in keyof obj]: ReducerToAction<obj[key]> }
```

So it looks something like this.

```
type ReducersToActions<R> = { [K in keyof R]: ReducerToAction<R[K]> }
```

## Step 3 - Extracting the `IActionPayload<number>` type

If you provide the `type` of what you are handling like so.

```
type IActionPayload <T> = { type: string, payload: T }
```

It seems you can access the keys. So if we place this also into a conditional we can pull the single key from the object.

```
type PullPayloadType<P> = P extends IActionPayload<any> ? P['payload'] : never
```

In English is should say if it is type `IActionPayload` we know it has the key `payload` so pull it else return `never`.

## Result

With this, we will need to update the other types to take this in which will give you the following.

```
// Action Structure
type IActionPayload <T> = { type: string, payload: T }
// Reducers object structure
type IReduces = { [key:string] : (state:any, payload:IActionPayload<any>) => any }
// Gets the Payload type from an object that is of type IActionPayload
type PullPayloadType<P> = P extends IActionPayload<any> ? P['payload'] : never
// Formats a Reducer Function to remove state and place the payload parameter as the first parameter
type ReducerToAction<R> = R extends (...args: infer A) => any ? (payload:PullPayloadType<A[1]>) => any : never
// Formats Reducer Functions in a object that matches the type IReduces
type ReducersToActions<R extends IReduces> = { [K in keyof R]: ReducerToAction<R[K]> }
```